# Need to load 5 Million entries from hazelcast map to another map while startup of application

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I want to load 5 Million entry from hazelcast IMap to another map but its taking too much of time. How can i optimize it so it should take lesser time and my application can come up as early as possible.Below is code snippet

```
    //localMap is another map where i want to put all entries from Hazelcast
    Map<Object, Object> localMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    //imap is hazelcast map reference
    Iterator<Object> itr = imap.keySet().iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Object obj = itr.next();
        localMap.put(obj, imap.get(obj));
    }
    //returning entry set of local map
    return localMap.entrySet().iterator();
```

Comment: Parallelize it to five threads, each copying only a million entries?

Comment: Can't you initialize your map in a background thread so that your application can start faster?

Comment: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/IMap.html#executeOnEntries-com.hazelcast.map.EntryProcessor- could help. But in general this looks like a design problem. How can you be sure the map contains the same values when you initialization logic finishes compared to the time it processed the key previously?

Comment: @Shark thanks for suggestions but the thing is how do i can divide it in 1M entries each thread?

Comment: @StephaneM No i can't, because i have some services which is dependent upon localmap and it should initialize first.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker It's not a design problem, i have a requirement where i have to read all the data which are in hazelcast map and initialize some services which is dependent upon localmap.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
IMap map = hc.getMap("some-map");
Map result = map.getAll(map.keySet());
```

but it would be an expensive operation. Or run a Predicate to retrieve all values, see doc: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#distributed-query

But this does look like a design problem, for you will have to accommodate all 5 million entries in your application jvm - increased memory footprint. Also, don't forget the network and ser/des overhead in moving those many entries at the same time.

If your use case is such then I suggest you also look to page your result set in small chunks, see Paging Predicate doc for more detail: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#filtering-with-paging-predicates